# "There is already an object named XXXX in the database" after creating New database

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an SQL file which I am executing on an SQL Server instance which contains the schema for a database. The file creates a brand new database (as in, a database with this name does not exist on this server):

```
CREATE DATABASE PROJECT;
```

and begins to create a relation:

```
CREATE TABLE Courses (
  CourseID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  Name VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
  Code CHAR(4) NOT NULL UNIQUE
);

...
```

and here is what SQL Server tells me right off the bat:

```
Msg 2714, Level 16, State 6, Line 3
There is already an object named 'Courses' in the database.
```

Any idea why SQL Server tells me that there already exists a relation by the name of `Courses` when clearly there isn't?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: after creating the database, try executing this query `USE PROJECT;`, and run the DDL again.

Comment: Ohhh.... It was going in the master DB... gotcha!

Comment: One drawback... After creating the `PROJECT` database and executing `USE PROJECT;` I get: `Msg 911, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
Database 'PROJECT' does not exist. Make sure that the name is entered correctly.`

Comment: In SSMS, you'll need a `GO` between the Create database, and the USE statement

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check the database if you are using `PROJECT`

```
CREATE DATABASE PROJECT
GO

USE PROJECT
GO

CREATE TABLE Courses 
(
  CourseID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  Name VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
  Code CHAR(4) NOT NULL UNIQUE
)
GO
```

Comment: I'm not real knowledgeable about the vendor specific T-SQL. Could you explain what `GO` does, in this case?

Comment: `GO` is not the same thing as `;` in mysql. Go separates batches of commands. `;` ends a statement (in both mysql and T-SQL) and many statements can be part of a batch. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188037.aspx

Comment: @M_M Hmm... I didn't know `;` wasn't required in TSQL! Thanks!

Comment: Generally not required except using Common table expressions. The `WITH` must either be the first stament in a batch, or be preceded with a `;`

Answer (score 3):

You are likely missing `USE PROJECT` statement and therefore trying to create Courses table in the **master** database, not in the PROJECT database.

Answer (score 0):

Long shot but try using:

```
Use project;
CREATE TABLE Courses....
```